# How would I go about making my own GIF launcher?

Tags: gif

I am trying to create a button on an app I'm working on that launches a GIF recording when I click the button. I'm not familiar with how GIFs are made or what resources I would need to create this. Are there any languages/tools I would need to know to do this?

Comment: what language are you using to make your app/website?

Comment: Mainly Python but also some Javascript, and HTML/CSS. The app was created by a team in my internship, I'm just adding new features as part of my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that plays the gif on click of a button or on click of the still image.

```js
number = 0;
var animations = ['https://media.giphy.com/media/sCPGYa9EAeTFC/giphy.gif',
  'https://media.giphy.com/media/sCPGYa9EAeTFC/giphy.gif',
  'https://media.giphy.com/media/sCPGYa9EAeTFC/giphy.gif'
]; // array of gif

//function to play gif
function playGif() {
  image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
  image.src = animations[number];
}
```

```css
.gifButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;
}

.board {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.board img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button class="gifButton" onclick="playGif()">Click to play Gif</button>
  <div class="board">
    <img src="https://im7.ezgif.com/tmp/ffffff-ezgif-7-0ed398c8bb8a-gif-jpg/frame_07_delay-0.13s.jpg" id="hiddenimageid" onclick="character();" />
  </div>
</body>

<!--The img src here is the still image to display before the gif starts running-->
```

Or if you are trying to just display the Gif from a link you could put it in an iframe

```css
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 40%;
  height 40%;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://giphy.com/embed/eoxomXXVL2S0E" width="480" height="360" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe>
<p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/internet-eoxomXXVL2S0E">via GIPHY</a></p>
```